# Create vector layer from feature collection in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, wfs, features, wps

I have used a WPS process `gs:UnionFeatureCollection` to compute the geographical union of two collections of WFS vector features. The process returns a collection of features which I intend to display on the map, first, by constructing a layer and adding it to the layer switcher.

```
 wpsClient.execute({
    server:'local',
    process:'gs:UnionFeatureCollection',
    inputs:{
        first:features1,
        second:features2
    },
    success:function(output){
        var features = output;
        localStorage.setItem("Feature", JSON.stringify(JSON.decycle(features)));
        window.location.reload();
    }
})
```

This is the code to execute the process. I am saving the resulting feature collection to browser LocalStorage and refreshing the browser window. During the loading a new vector layer is being created and added to an array of layers that will be added to the map.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("Feature") != null){
    var features = JSON.retrocycle(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Feature")));
    var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Union Layer");
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(features);
    layers.push(vectorLayer);
}
```

Here is my problem, the layer does appear on the layer switcher but not on the map even when enabled. Is defining features for the layer sufficient to display it or do I need to add it to the geoserver? (I'm pretty new to web mapping but not so much to javascript)